# File put content does not write to file edwin.txt

Tags: php

File put content does not write to file edwin.txt

```
file_put_contents('files/'. 'edwin'. ".txt", $array_data);
$array_data =[ '$first_name' => $first_name, '$last_name' => $last_name,
'$password' => $password, '$username' => $username, '$dob'=> $dob,
'$confirm_password' => $confirm_password ]
```

Comment: You must convert your array into a string representation.

Comment: Or possibly even define the data before the function call. // In any case: questions can't just be code dumps and vague problem allusions.

Comment: What happens instead? What have you tried to fix the problem?

Comment: This has been settled